# Zend_Dom_Query selector for second element

Tags: php, zend-dom-query

```
<div id="test">
<span>Don't select me</span>
<span>Select me</span>
</div>
```

I want to select second span in `div#test`.
Exist `eq()` selector (like jQuery) or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately `Zend_Dom_Query` doesn't support the `:nth-child(n)` selector from css, but reverting back to `xpath` to query you could write:

```
 $result = $dom->queryXpath('//div[@id="test"]/span[2]');
```

The `Zend_Dom_Query` library uses xpath behind a scenes to execute CSS style queries so, if you got struck with xpath syntax, you can take a sneak peek into what's it generated with the `getXpathQuery` method on the result objects.